# How to safely treat data from JSON when the expected type may differ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa

As of iOS 5 and OSX 10.7 and higher it is really easy to parse JSON with `NSJSONSerialization`, which will return either an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` (or mutable variants, if specified) when parsing JSON. Values are parsed as common Cocoa types such as `NSString` and `NSNumber` however I would be interested to know how careful I need to be when taking the data from the `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` and parsing it into data objects in my app. My key concerns are whether the key's value a) is not nil and b) isn't of an unexpected type.

For example, assume I had the following JSON object:

```
{
  "version":1,
  "title":"Some interesting title",
  "info":"Some detail here"
}
```

Currently, this would be parsed as an NSDictionary:

```
@{
  @"version": @1,
  @"title":@"Some interesting title",
  @"info": @"Some detail here"
}
```

My problem is how careful I should be when checking the data types of what I'm getting back. In theory, if I'm using a good API I should always get a numeric value for the version key, but what if for some reason it is changed server side to the following:

```
{ "version:"1", ... }
```

Or even worse:

```
{ "version:"one", ... }
```

If I attempt the following code, I will get hit an exception and my app would crash:

```
NSNumber * myNumber = dictionary[@"version"];
if ([myNumber isEqualToNumber:@1])
{
   ...
}
```

The code wouldn't execute because a) `dictionary[@"version"]` would be an NSString and b) isEqualToNumber: is only available on NSNumber (unrecognized selector exception, app would crash).

Equally, problems could arise if the JSON for "info" was changed to the following:

```
{
   "info":{
     "code":200,
     "message":"Some detail here"
   }
}
```

If my app expects an `NSString` for the key `info` it will again crash, because an NSDictionary will have been found instead.

On the large part, most JSON from an API or file should be sound and supported by the current version of the app and one would hope that all JSON is versioned and correctly encoded server side. In some cases, if the JSON has been corrupted or modified, the app could crash, which I want to avoid.

Potential solutions:

- Check every single key/value pair for `isKindOfClass:` or `respondsToSelector:` and only continue if true
- Check the key exists and produce an error if nil
- Wrap up  everything in a try/catch block, however I would rather what can be used is used and an error is produced if something is wrong with the data. This could end up with a lot of @try/@catch statements inside one another

Each of these solutions is rather bulky and adds a lot to my code which I would prefer to avoid, if possible (and when working with 'good' JSON it is perfectly possible). If there is an alternative solution that will handle the process of parsing JSON, checking keys' type and values before putting it in a custom object I would love to know.

Comment: In C#/.NET I always deserialize to a "POCO" (depending on what I wanted, I could map the values, discard the values, or explode). Is there such a way to automatically map (and verify the data) in Obj-C?

Comment: @user2246674 unfortunately there is not a native way to do this in Obj-C.

Comment: Bummer :( I was poking around, and I found https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/ - although something like that might be very much overkill.

Comment: @user2246674 in my case it is probably slight overkill, and in my current project I'm working with local JSON files rather than those from the web anyway (although I imagine RestKit works just as well with them).

Comment: RestKit is perfectly happy to use local files. Your main concern is that it isn't as fast as writing your own code to handle the input data...

Comment: @Wain speed isn't a concern - whether or not is is overkill to use a third party library when there could be a simpler solution or platform level support is my main concern.

Comment: You probably won't find a simpler solution than RestKit. Platform support, you already listed it and you need to write it yourself. You could create a number of helper functions to prevent lots of duplication but that's about it. Those functions could both check and mutate the data type if written well.

Comment: If `NSString` and `NSNumber` are the only two possibilities for the thing you're worried about, you could coerce whatever it is: `[val integerValue];`, for example.

Comment: The general solution is to use `isKindOfClass` where required.  In any reasonable scenario, though, the number of possible variations should be small and pretty well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally be running against a stable API. The kind of changes you're worried about should be accompanied by a version number change in any reasonable system which would insulate your app from the change until an appropriate upgrade time. So, you should generally know the data type to expect.

In some cases the API will specify that a dictionary or an array may be received depending on the multiplicity, something like that. In this case you should check the class and act accordingly.

You should definitely check for `nil` and `NSNull` and handle those gracefully.

Corrupted JSON should be handled by the parser and an appropriate error returned to you.

Also, you could use a framework like RestKit to do the mapping to your custom objects for you. It does a lot of data type checking as standard and removes basically all of your mapping code into a simple configuration. It also handles all of the network comms (via AFNetworking).

Comment: RestKit does seem like a sensible solution, although I agree that most of the time I would be working against a stable API (although in the past I've seen APIs completely switch data structures overnight with no versioning). Equally, I've also seen APIs that will sometimes return an integer for a value or sometimes return an integer in quotes.

Comment: @ProgrammingThomas: One example was an API delivering information about clothing, where a dress size of 14 was reported as a number, but a dress size "14-16" was reported as a string. Endless fun.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your code is safe against attacks from hackers. When you request JSON from a server, you must expect that the data doesn't come from your server but from somewhere else, and that someone else might have designed the data returned to cause maximum damage. Now just crashing if you receive a string instead of a number is quite secure.

You must expect that your request to the server is instead fulfilled by some brain damaged hardware that tries to be "helpful" for example when an internet connection fails. Instead of JSON you might receive a "helpful" website that is supposed to tell a user how to reset their router. A user trying to use someone's free WiFi may have connections return weird result. That's usually no problem with JSON because the parsing will fail (so failed parsing is something you should expect and handle), more of a problem if you expect html.

You must expect that a public API that you are using has bugs or unexpected behaviour and you should behave well when that happens. Add debugging code that will at least log anything unexpected while you are developing. Write your code so that it works with any behaviour that the API shows.

If you are using your own API, you should also log anything unexpected, and then tell the server people if they do anything they shouldn't.